# Math mode and beamer

Tags: beamer, math-mode

I have some difficulties with math mode in `beamer`.

At the moment if I add a newline it gives the error message:

```
Missing $ inserted. \end{frame}
```

What am I doing wrong?

In another question it has something to do with versions of math-package and `beamer`, but I have a fresh install.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Example Quadratic Formula}
    \begin{columns}
        \column{0.5\textwidth}
        Dicriminant
        \begin{math}
            \text{function } \left[d\right]=\text{dicriminant}(a, b, c)
            d = b\wedge 2 - 4*a*c
        \end{math} 
        \column{0.5\textwidth}
        some text
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This doesn't work:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Example Quadratic Formula}
    \begin{columns}
        \column{0.5\textwidth}
        Dicriminant
        \begin{math}
            \text{function } \left[d\right]=\text{dicriminant}(a, b, c)\\
            d = b\wedge 2 - 4*a*c
        \end{math} 
        \column{0.5\textwidth}
        some text
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\\ ` is not intended for use in `math` , better to use a multi-line math environment such as `align*` or `gather*`

Comment: Should it not be *b squared* instead of *b wedge 2*? Or am I missing some of the math here?

Comment: You should write `\operatorname{discriminant}` rather than `\text{discriminant}`.  Besides the discriminant is given by $d = b^2 - 4ac$.

Comment: @BMWurm No you don't missing something. I need it for visual needs

Comment: @Jan-Bert Thanks for the explanation :D

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need some math environment with multi-line support. There is `align*`, `gather*`, `split`, `multline`, `aligned`, `alignat`, and the list continues..

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,lmodern}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Example Quadratic Formula}
    \begin{columns}
        \column{0.5\textwidth}
        Dicriminant
        \begin{align*}
            \text{function } \left[d\right]&=\text{dicriminant}(a, b, c)\\
            d &= b\wedge 2 - 4*a*c
        \end{align*}
        \column{0.5\textwidth}
        some text
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 6):

The `math`-environment is designed to show "inline" math formulae.  The word "inline" implies, that the math is presented in the normal running text.  Therefore it can't break lines by using <kbd>Ret</kbd> or `\\`.  You have to encounter each line in a `\begin{math} ... \end{math}`environment of its own, like so:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Example Quadratic Formula}
    \begin{columns}
        \column{0.5\textwidth}
        Dicriminant
        \begin{math}
            \text{function } \left[d\right]=\text{dicriminant}(a, b, c)
        \end{math} 
        \begin{math}
            d = b\wedge 2 - 4*a*c
        \end{math}
        \column{0.5\textwidth}
        some text
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This works without compilation error.

Despite that, in your case, I would ask you, to use an environment, which was designed for displayed formulae, as you display the formulae as a paragraph of is own right.

A displayed formulae is typeset different, compared to an inline formulae.  The font is bigger, the position of the sub- and superscripts is different, ...  Do yourself the favour and enjoy the typographic enhancement.

Therefore, I suggest you use something like an `eqnarray` environment or something similar from the AMS packages, e. g. `align`:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Example Quadratic Formula}
    \begin{columns}
        \column{0.5\textwidth}
        Discriminant
        \begin{align}
          \text{function} \left[d\right] &= \text{discriminant}(a, b, c)\\
          \Delta &= b^2 - 4\cdot a\cdot c
        \end{align}
        \column{0.5\textwidth}
        some text
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Which compiles without error and results in

[image]